# PHP Switching between two variables equally without using database

Tags: php, variables, switching

i need to switch between two variables so i am able to serve two variables equally

for example i have

```
$ad1
$ad2
```

i want to serve both ads equally using a light method with no database

using random method won't serve both equally

can you please guide me how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

But the random method (50/50) should serve both equally, given enough requests.

And it is the simplest solution imho.

```
<?php
$ad1 = '<img src... >';
$ad2 = '<img src...2 >';

echo mt_rand(0, 1) ? $ad1 : $ad2;
?>
```

Comment: can you please explain more on how to apply 50% to php random function .. thanks

Comment: I think what he wants is toggle between variables each time a new request comes

Comment: @Netcaster: The law of big numbers says that in the long run it WILL be 50/50.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use memcache (recommended)
- You can keep track of the last used variable in a file on the server (not recommended)
- You can use time() and use its mod by 2 as your decision maker (still not an exactly equality as you wanted)

(I think, on the long run, rand will serve you great)